# How to achieve Tree Structure UI in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to achieve Tree Structure like UI in React-Native. There is no specific library available for this kind of functionality. Can anyone guide in this. Which libraries will be helpful to achieve it? or What is the right way to go ahead with?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-family-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-family-tree)
 to achieve this.
But beware as this is not maintained anymore.

Comment: Thanks Hassan. I hv checked the library. Creator of the library has used FlatList to acheive the functionality. To represent tree it is good, but when it comes to Expand and Collapse feature library will lack.